# Use boolean to search duplicate

Tags: java, boolean, duplicates

I want to use boolean to search duplicate when I need to print out a list of names. So I need to write a program to read names in a text file and print it out to console. But the compiler doesn't work in this case. I don't know why? Can you guys help me?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class NameSorter 
{

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    BufferedReader cin, fin;
    cin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

     //Description
    System.out.println("Programmer: Minh Nguyen");
    System.out.println("Description: This program is to sort names stored in a file.");
    System.out.println();
    //Get input
    String fileName;
    System.out.print("Enter the file's name: ");
    fileName = cin.readLine();
    fin = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    int nNames = 0;
    String[] name = new String[8];

    //initialize array elements
    for(int i=0; i<name.length;i++)
    {
        name[i]=" ";
    }
    // read text file
    while(fin.ready())
    {
      String aName = fin.readLine();
      String temp =  aName;
      boolean check;
      if(temp.compareTo(" ")>0)
      {

          for(int i=0; i<name.length;i++)
          {
              if(temp.compareToIgnoreCase(name[i])==0)
              {
                  check = true;
                  break;
              }


          }

      }               
          if(nNames<name.length&& check = false)
          {
              name[nNames++] = temp;
          }

      }


    }
    fin.close();

    // Sort the names aphabetically.
    for(int i=0;i<nNames; i++)
    {
      int j;
      for(j=i+1;j<nNames; j++)
      {       
          if(name[i].compareToIgnoreCase(name[j])>0)
          {
          String temp = name[i];
          name[i] = name[j];
          name[j] = temp;            
          }  
      }
    }

    for(int i=0; i<name.length;i++)
        System.out.println(name[i]);

  }

}
```

Comment: It would help if you'd include the error message you're seeing.  "It doesn't work" just marks you in a way you'd prefer it didn't.  Also, try changing `check = false` to `check == false`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is :

```
if(nNames<name.length && check = false)
```

`check= false` , assigns `false` to `check`. To compare `check` with `false` you can use
`check==false`or `!check`.

Depending on what you are trying to validate. The below code will remove the compilation error:

```
check == false //checks if check is false
```

Or,

```
if(nNames<name.length && (check = false))
// above is same as if(nNames<name.length && false) // which will always be false
```

Comment: Thanks, It can compile now but I still dont get a desired result.I need to read names in a text file. My algorithm is first I will skip blank lines in the file and then skip duplicates and finally assign proper values to array-based list and print them out. I know my program doesnt work but I dont know why:(. Can you guys give me some clue. I have to use array-based list because this is the requirement for my homework.

Comment: Can someone help, so desperate!

Comment: I grabbed your code, fixed it according to this answer, then also found an extra curly brace that I removed. I compiled it and ran it against a text file with a list of names and it works.

Comment: Great that you found it out yourself !